# XML security during website sign-up

Tags: security, privacy

I am developing a website which involves a user being able to sign up using their name and e-mail address. I'm looking for a little advice, however, around how to store those details in the most secure way.

My initial thought was to store them in an XML file using JSON, but that isn't particularly safe (at least, not the way I was intending to do it).

I am currently using a .NET server, but if necessary I can swap over to PHP if that helps.

I'm open to any advice the community might offer in regards to my implementation.

Comment: Retagged to exclude jQuery.  This is not a jQuery question.

Comment: Kenneth, if you found my answer below helpful, please vote it up and/or mark it as the answer accordingly.  If you have further questions, please let me know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some random notes, since this is a big issue and hard to put simply.

- "in an XML-file with JSON" - This makes no sense since JSON and XML are both string-based data structures.  Often you'll use XML *or* JSON, not both.  You certainly don't want a .XML file that contains JSON data.  That's what the .JSON file extension is for.
- In terms of security, stashing user creds in an XML file (or any file) on the file system is a good way to get your site hacked and your user creds stolen.  Most secure is to store it in a database (such as MySQL or SQL Server) and encrypt the sensitive user data (passwords, etc).  Next best would be to encrypt that XML file.  The downsides are that it's less secure, less flexible and generally terrible practice as far as production websites go, but people have done worse while just learning.  All large applications will store and access user data from databases.
- You said users will "sign up."  That means you'll have some advanced logic on your side as far as authentication, registration, roles, etc.  All of this will be a LOT easier in a database.

Personally, I suggest you read up on [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx).  You don't need to buy a database and you can deploy it like a file, meanwhile getting all the benefits of using a real database.  Just be sure to encrypt user passwords and any other sensitive information you store about your users.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Adam. Thank you for your reply. What I mean with "Sign Up", is that you sign-up for a cause. Like when you sign up, on a landing-page/splash-site/under-contruction-website etc.. My website is fairly simple, and I don't have any back-end what so ever. I have MySQL on my server, and would very much like to know how to store user creds in that. Where should I look? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the question, he just needs to store names and email addresses. Where the advanced logic comes into play beats me. XML and/or JSON does not affect security. A database isn't necessarily more secure than the file system. He would of course save the encrypted file outside of the webroot.

Comment: @Kenneth - You say that you don't have "any back-end what so ever," which confuses me a little bit.  Do you mean that your server environment doesn't support a server-side script such as PHP, C#, or something of that sort?  That seems contradictory to your original post.  After doing a simple Google search, I found this resource that looks like it might be of value: http://www.webassist.com/free-downloads/tutorials-and-training/database-for-php/  Let me know if it helps answer some of your questions.

Comment: @k_b - Your lack of tact aside, I strongly suggest you read up on the topic: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/storing-data-with-php-flat-file-or-database.html.  There are numerous advantages a database has over flat files for data storage in terms of security and ease of data retrieval.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to use a database, store it in an encrypted file. The format doesn't matter.

Comment: To suggest this without listing the numerous security risks and pitfalls is a disservice to the OP.